# Solr How to query a single character

Tags: solr, character

What kind of TokenizerFactories should be split the word to some characters,
just like 'abc' => 'a','b','c'
I had used some of the TokenizerFactories such as KeywordTokenizerFactory,WhitespaceTokenizerFactory,StandardTokenizerFactory.etc.
but i don't complete it.
who can help me,thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `FilterFactory` along with your desired `TokenizerFactory`. `NGramFilterFactory` could be of your interest. Have a look at its [documentation](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-NGramFilter).

Comment: I had solved the problem by your answers,thank you very much for your help.